# How do i check my Wireless earbuds Battery?

Tags: bluetooth, xiaomi, bluetooth-audio

Okay, So I don't really know What's the appropriate section of StackExchange to post this question, But I'd like recommendations on that.

So i'm using new wireless earbuds that I bought earlier this week, And when i pair them to another phone (A Samsung Galaxy S10+ in this case) It seems to show battery information under the Bluetooth device's name. e.g(Battery : 100%)

Although, when i use the earbuds with my tablet (An extremely laggy and weak Lenovo tablet) It seems to show nothing under the Device's name... What can i do to make it show the Battery information? where can i get battery information about my Xiaomi earbuds?

Comment: According to this [blog post](https://www.addictivetips.com/android/view-battery-levels-for-bluetooth-devices-android/) battery status of Bluetooth devices is only showing on devices running Android 8.1 or higher. Older system requires an app like [BatOn](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.limi.baton&rdid=com.limi.baton) to show the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to this question, As User @Robert commented on my post, And i installed BatOn And now the battery usage shows up. Thank you!.